# Carrierwave in modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, carrierwave

This is my model in /app/library/stone.rb

```
class Library::Stone < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :group, :healing, :life, :logo, :magic, :name, :other, :place,    :structure, :view

   mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader

   before_save :cap_group

   def cap_group
     self.name = self.name.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s
     self.group = self.name[0]
   end

end
```

This is the uploader /app/uploaders/logo_uploader.rb

```
class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
     "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 300]
  end

end
```

The problem is that this works in the console, but when I try it in the browser, the image is not uploaded properly. I think it is because somehow the

Answer (score 0):

try see your development log, and see what error it show.

Or try to able to 'module' RMagick in your Uploader like this : https://github.com/lccezinha/rails3-twitter-bootstrap/blob/master/app/uploaders/archive_uploader.rb and in your Gemfile include

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
```

and run the bundle command

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I have already installed those gems and uncommented the *include CarrierWave::RMagick* in the uploader, but still nothing. The development log shows everything is OK.

Comment: Have you ever try other browser ? Try change the dir where the uploaded will be saved